# Compare numeric values two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i hace this issue whit two arrays

one array is given by a json like this

```
array1( [0] => 6, [1] => 1)
```

and making a query i got this other

```
array2( [0] => 1, [1] => 1)
```

I want to compare both arrays and use "if" when numeric values of array1 are less than or equal to array2. Is that possible? like this?

```
if($array1 <= $array2){do something}
```

Grettings!

Comment: What if one array has key 0 <= other but key 1 is > other?

Comment: maybe this will be ok for you `if(array_sum($array1) <= array_sum($array2)) { ... `

Comment: What if they are [1,4] and [2,3] ? Which one should be greater? Is the number of elements in arrays always the same?

Comment: I suppose that you are trying to compare the sum, if not, can you explain it better?

Comment: If you don't compare sums like these other suggestions, you'll need to look through array2 and find if any of them are greater than the values in array1 (do they correspond or do you check all values in array1?)

Comment: the json sends me something like this 'Array([0] => Array([sku] => 014633368987 [quantity] => 5) [1] => Array ([sku] => 885370145717 [quantity] => 1))' the i sorted and extract the quantity and sku values to new arrays the sku values is what i use to do the query and give the array like first but with quantity values on my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what your expected behaviour is, and also the expectations of your two arrays.  For the sake of these examples, **I'm going to assume that each array is guaranteed to be the same size** and you are compairing **paired elements** (elements from each array at the same index).

---

If you want to exit **the first time a number from array1 is less than its paired element from array2**:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array1); $i++) {
    if ($array1[$i] <= $array2[$i]) {
        ...do something
    }
}
```

---

If you want to **do something if all values of array1 are less than their paired elements from array2**:

```
// Keep track of a flag so we know if we meet our condition once done
$allValuesLessThan = true;

// Check each individual array1 element and its 'paired element' from array2
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array1); $i++) {
    // If we break our condition, set our flag and break out of our loop, since we no longer need to check subsequent elements
    if ($array1[$i] > $array2[$i]) {
        $allValuesLessThan = false;
        break;
    }
}

// Finally, only do our 'something' if our condition was met
if ($allValuesLessThan) {
    ...do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thats exactly what i want to do!